# Reload django wsgi scripts without root

Tags: django, django-wsgi

I have an install of django on apache using embedded wsgi. I DON'T have root on the machine.

How can I tell apache to reload the python instance when I deploy new source code?

I tried removing all the .pyc files and it still is running the old code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

This article about reloading source code with mod_wsgi goes into how to reload source code, and even how to create a monitor script to automatically reload the daemon when you make source changes. It's really good for setting up a development environment using mod_wsgi.

Comment: That link seems to recommend `MaxRequestsPerChild 1` which will kill my performance. I was looking for a way to reload it whenever I do a push.

Comment: You don't have to use that... check out the next three sections in the article about daemon mode and code change monitoring.

Comment: Daemon mode is the answer. Two lines in the apache config, and it doesn't cost must performance. thanks

Comment: The document actually says about MaxRequestsPerChild that 'using this method is not recommended'. So, although it explains that you can do it, you really should use mod_wsgi daemon mode instead. It definitely isn't being recommended as you suggest.

Answer (score 14):

If you are running mod_wsgi in daemon mode with apache, you may not have to restart apache to get it to reload.

I just touch my wsgi file (unix: touch updates the 'saved date' of a file) and apache reloads it on next access/web-hit.

See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

... as long as you can alter the timestamp on the WSGI script.

Comment: "touch filename.wsgi" is the correct way to do it, and does not require root or restarting apache. Since I generally only want to do this immediately after checking out new code, I set up an alias to get latest code and touch the wsgi at the same time, e.g.:

alias upcrest='cd /home/crest/sites/projects/ourcrestmont; svn up; touch /home/crest/our/ourcrestmont.wsgi'

Comment: There are quiet a few catch, see http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Reloading_In_Embedded_Mode